# Joomla - menu item - home button

Tags: url, joomla, menu, joomla1.5, menuitem

I am trying to do a simple straightforward thing but it wont work.
Can anybody help me figure this out:

In mainmenu of Joomla (1.5) I have a button called "Home".
This link should redirect to the homepage of the website.
It is set as the default and has the right article in place.

Instead of linking to www.mydomain.com it uses the aliasname and adds it to the url www.mydomain.com/home

**How can I make a simple Home button that redirects to the homepage?**

If I use Alias or external link I get 404 because the article is not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose home menu type as link and give the proper link in the link section.

Then you should create an article with no content and assign this to a new menu item then make that menu item as default menu. (Bcoz joomla needs any article as its home page).
Then in the home page you can write some conditions like

```
$PageUrl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$pageName = '';
$pageUrlRemPart = substr($PageUrl, strrpos($PageUrl, '/') + 1, strlen($PageUrl));
    if($pageUrlRemPart!="" && $pageUrlRemPart!="index.php")
    $homePage   =   false;
    else
    $homePage   =   true;
```

based on this home page you can load the component type this should check inside the template/index.php

Comment: Wow (!) all this for a simple button that links to the homepage article and its url?

Comment: or your home page should contain an article then you can simply assign that to default menu.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of linking it to the article for the Homepage, you could set the "type" of the menu item to "external link", then simply set the link to http://mydomain.com

Hope this help.

Comment: @SailesHardt: are you using K2 or the standard Joomla articles?

Comment: linking to external url isn't applicable for home menu item